# What are Range and Index types in C# 8?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

In C# 8, two new types are added to the System namespace: [`System.Index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.index) and [`System.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range).

How do they work and when can we use them?

Comment: https://blog.cdemi.io/whats-coming-in-c-8-0-ranges-and-indices/

Comment: I can recomment this for a short intro (section Index and Range): https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-preview-3

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They're used for indexing and slicing.
From [Microsoft's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/building-c-8-0/#ranges-and-indices):

Indexing:

```
Index i1 = 3;  // number 3 from beginning
Index i2 = ^4; // number 4 from end
int[] a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
Console.WriteLine($"{a[i1]}, {a[i2]}"); // "3, 6"
```

Range (slicing):

> We’re also introducing a Range type, which consists of two Indexes,
> one for the start and one for the end, and can be written with a x..y
> range expression. You can then index with a Range in order to produce
> a slice:

```
var slice = a[i1..i2]; // { 3, 4, 5 }
```

You can use them in `Array`, `String`, `[ReadOnly]Span` and `[ReadOnly]Memory` types, so you have another way to make substrings:

```
string input = "This a test of Ranges!";
string output = input[^7..^1];
Console.WriteLine(output); //Output: Ranges
```

You can also omit the first or last Index of a Range:

```
output = input[^7..]; //Equivalent of input[^7..^0]
Console.WriteLine(output); //Output: Ranges!

output = input[..^1]; //Equivalent of input[0..^1]
Console.WriteLine(output); //Output: This a test of Ranges
```

You can also save ranges to variables and use them later:

```
Range r = 0..^1;
output = input[r];
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: So Index from end are 1 based and Range from end are 0 based? That's confusing.

Comment: Does `"abc"[0..1]` alloc new string?

Comment: @Maxter It's better to think of indexes as referring to the gaps between characters. 0 is before the first character; 1 is between first and second, ^1 is between second-to-last and last, and ^0 is after the last.
Ranges always select the characters between the two gaps.
Accessing a single element always gives you the element after the gap.

Comment: Thx Daniel, this actually helped.

Answer (score 0):

**System.Index**
Excellent way toindex a collection from the ending.
(Which can be used to obtain the collection from the beginning or from the end).

**System.Range**
Ranges way to access "ranges" or "slices" of collections. This will help you to avoid LINQ and making your code compact and more readable. (Access a sub-collection(slice) from a collection).

***More Info in my articles:***

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-8-features/

https://www.infoq.com/articles/cs8-ranges-and-recursive-patterns